# Permission denied when starting Unicorn on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-11.04, unicorn

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu and some problem with server settings for my Rails app.

I've created deployer user in admin group (%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL). It was all ok, but when I'm trying to start Unicorn service, getting Permission denied message:

```
deployer@myvpsserver:~$ /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start
-bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp: Permission denied
```

Here is my /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp:

```
!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/myapp/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
```

Result of ls -l /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 63 Aug  8 23:13 /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp ->      
/home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn_init.sh
```

Comment: Can you post your /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp script?  Also, post the output from ls -l /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp

Comment: I've added unicorn_myapp :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need `sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start`, or else set the executable bit on the init script with `chmod a+x /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp`.  None of this is Ubuntu-specific stuff, though.

Comment: Thanks! When I've tried *sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start  
[sudo] password for deployer: mypass
sudo: /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp: command not found* I'll try to change mode in some minutes.

Comment: With chmod anyway `-bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_turbostartum: Permission denied` :(

Comment: So `chmod` that, too.

Comment: Thanks to you and Chris McCauley! With `chmod a+x /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn_init.sh` it works now :)